# Is IOKit a Mac-only framework?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

is it possible to work with IOKit using the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 1):

At least you can compile an app using IOKit with iOS SDK.

```
$ sudo ln -s /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Headers /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework
```

Actually, I could compile libusb for iOS, however libusb doesn't work on iPad iOS 4.2 for unknown reason.

Also it should be rejected by Apple if you submit an app using IOKit.